# container doesn't want to display full screen

Tags: react-native, flexbox, styles

my container doesn't want to display full width.. even though I have written the code as below, is there something wrong?

all my style code was here, I gave the background color to show there is a space at the end, and how to remove this until the color become fullscreen

[image: code styles]

this the code from name.txs

```
render() {
        return (
            <Container style = {styles.container}>
                <VStack alignItems="center" alignContent="center">
                    <View style = {styles.view}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:12, textAlign:'center'}}>
                            Please Input your Name
                        </Text>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Enter Your Name Here'
                            onChangeText={ (name) => this.props.authStore.setName(name)}
                        />
                    </View> 
                    
                    <View style = {styles.view}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:12, textAlign:'center'}}>
                            Month of Your Born
                        </Text>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='January, February, etc.'
                            onChangeText={ (month) => this.props.authStore.setMonth(month)}
                        />
                    </View> 
                    
                    <View style = {styles.view}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:12, textAlign:'center'}}>
                            Day of Your Born
                        </Text>
                        <TextInput 
                            keyboardType="numeric"

                            placeholder='1-31'
                            onChangeText={ (day) => this.props.authStore.setDay(day)}
                        />

                    </View> 

                    <View style = {styles.view}>
                        <Button
                            title="Submit"
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Zodiac')}/>
                    </View>
                </VStack>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Attach the JSX Code also

Comment: I updated my question, can u help me?

Comment: try adding `width: 100%` to `VStack` component.

Comment: width:'100%' causes the component to take 100% width of parent component. Your parent component probably isn't taking full screen width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `<Container>` with `<Center flex={1}>` from NativeBase